# How to delete parent item in a transaction in dynamodb given that the count of children (ie other rows in the db) is 0

Tags: tree, transactions, amazon-dynamodb

I have a row in dynamodb (parent node) that I want to delete but only if it has no children, ie other rows in the same table.

I need to use a transaction deleteitem but not sure what to put in the condition expression.

Am I correct in thinking that a condition expression can't do count or scan or queries in dynamodb for other rows?

I was thinking of putting a count or version in the parent row but then if I add a child, I need to update the parent in the same transaction batch. My understanding is that dynamo doesn't let two transaction write items update different rows in the same table in the same transaction batch.

I would like to avoid creating new tables but if we create a table (parent -> child count), it would be possible to delete the item but that requires provisioning and maintaining another table.

Is there a solution that doesn't require me to create another table and/or a gap in my understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I correct in thinking that a condition expression can't do count or
> scan or queries in dynamodb for other rows?

Yes.

> I was thinking of putting a count or version in the parent row but then if I add a child, I need to update the parent in the same transaction batch.

Right.

> My understanding is that dynamo doesn't let two transaction write items update different rows in the same table in the same transaction batch.

Your understanding here is (happily) wrong. The whole point of transactions is to update two different items in the same batch atomically.

So my advice is keep the count in the parent row, transactionally, and leverage it with the delete condition.